# Return the strings that are smaller (lexicographically) from a given string

Tags: c

Given array of strings, its size and another 1 string, I need to return an array of strings, which these strings are `<` (**lexicographically**) from the given string. Also: return the length of the returned array using given pointer `size_res`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** LowerSTR(char* arr[], int size_arr, char* str, int* size_res) {
    size_t i, j;
    char** barr = malloc(size_arr);
    *size_res = 0;
    ------> printf("TEST"); <-----

    for(i=0; i<size_arr; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<strlen(str); j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == '\0' || (int)(arr[i][j]) < (int)(str[j])) {
                barr[(*size_res)++] = arr[i];
                break;
            }
            else if ((int)(arr[i][j]) == (int)(str[j])) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (*size_res == 0) return NULL;
    return barr;
}
```

I tried to test my code with this main:

```
int main() {
    int* len;
    char* arr[] = {"hello", "hola"};
    char** ans = LowerSTR(arr, 2, "bonjour", len);
    printf("%d", *len);

    return 0;
}
```

But the line above the test `printf`(highlighted with `----> <----` in the function) causes error: `segmentation fault` - I cannot understand why..

code with `strcmp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** LowerSTR(char* arr[], int size_arr, char* str, int* size_res) {
    size_t i;
    char** barr = malloc(size_arr);
    *size_res = 0;

    for(i=0; i<size_arr; i++) {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], str) <= 0)
            barr[(*size_res)++] = arr[i];
    }

    if (*size_res == 0) return NULL;
    return barr;
}
```

Comment: You pass `len` as parameter `size_res`, but `len` itself is a pointer which is uninitialized. Change `int* len` to `int len` and change the argument from `, len` to `, &len`.

Comment: Why do you compute the string length every time through the loop?  Why not compute it once, before entering the loop, and save the result?

Comment: You do not allocate enough space for `barr`.  You provide space sufficient for `size_arr` *bytes*, but you need up to enough space for that many *pointers* (to `char`).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205107/discussion-on-question-by-tal-rofe-return-the-strings-that-are-smaller-lexicogr).